# How can I show differential equation of the form can be transformed into a separable differential equation?

Tags: homogeneous-equation

Here is my question:

If $H(x,y)$ is a homogeneous function of degree n, show that the differential equation of the form 
$$y^nf(x) + H(x,y)(ydx - xdy) = 0$$
can be transformed into a separable differential equation.

How can I solve it?